# exponent manipulation - $4^{21} \cdot 5^{11} = 2 \cdot  10^{n}$ - what is $n$?

Tags: exponentiation

I was taking a practice GMAT test and it had a question like this:

$4^{21} \cdot  5^{11} = 2 \cdot  10^n$

What is $n$?

The available answers were something like
16
22
23
24
32

I'm not exactly sure on the multiple choice options...

However I'm not allowed a calculator so I'm not sure how to go about this...

I'm generally pretty good at the little tricks that allow you to solve a questions without the calculator but I have no idea how to do this one...

Thanks!

Update:

I found the actual question:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $4^{11}$ and not $4^{21}$?

Comment: no, that I have seen before, this is deff 21, because I remember the two exponents added up to 32

Comment: looks like I mixed up the exp/base combination there though... I posted the real question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! They were very prompt and helpful!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant $4^{11}\cdot 5^{21} = 2\cdot 10^n$. The rules you want to know for exponents can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation (this page has a lot of information, so depending on what you need, you may only be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties ). For this question, in particular, you want
\begin{align*}
 (a\cdot b)^n &= a^n\cdot b^n\ \ \operatorname{and}\newline
 a^{nm} &= (a^n)^m
\end{align*}

So looking at $10^n = (2\cdot 5)^n$, we get
\begin{align*}
 4^{11}\cdot 5^{21} &= (2^2)^{11}\cdot 5^{21}\newline
                &= 2^{22}\cdot 5^{21}\newline
                &= 2\cdot (2^{21}\cdot 5^{21}).
\end{align*}

So if you question was with the exponents reversed on the 4 and 5, we get that $n=21$.

Comment: You get a star for figuring out what the real question was lol

Comment: @kralco: The common thread of all these answers is recognizing the prime factorization of numbers, knowing rules of exponents, and applying the fact that there is equality.

Comment: Ya, I didn't think to factor the base to get them in the form I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I hope it was a question *like* that one, and not exactly that one. $4=2^2$, so $4^{21}=(2^2)^{21}=2^{42}$. $2\times5=10$, so $2^{11}\times5^{11}=10^{11}$. So $$4^{21}\times5^{11}=2^{42}\times5^{11}=2^{31}\times2^{11}\times5^{11}=2^{31}\times10^{11}$$

Trying to write it as $2\times10^n$ for some $n$ will only work if you allow $n$ to be a decimal number, not a whole number.

Comment: I updated my question to include a screen shot of the actual question which I was able to find... thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 3):

Updating in light of the corrected question.  Here are the basic rules that would allow you to solve a problem like this:

- $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$
- $(a^n)^m=a^{(mn)}$
- $a^{m+n}=a^m a^n$

So if we want to analyze $4^{11} * 5^{21}$, we see that we could use the first rule to combine things if we had terms that were all to the same power (which will be the $21$st power), and if we had a $2^{21}$ it would combine with the $5^{21}$ to make a $10^{21}$ (which is a term we want, given that we want to have $10^n$), which motivates the following series of equalities:
$$4^{11}5^{21}=(2^2)^{11}5^{21}=2^{22}5^{21}=2^{1} 2^{21}5^{21}=2*10^{21}.$$

Comment: sorry about the question, I was remembering it incorrectly, I was able to go back and find it however, and posted an update in my question.

Comment: is that last part supposed to be 2*10^11 or 2*10^21?

Comment: It should be ^21.  I went through and changed my answers when the question got updated, looks like I missed a spot.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing powers of $5$ in $\rm\:2\cdot 10^n = 5^{21}\cdot 4^{11}\:$ immediately yields $\rm\: n = 21\:.$

Comment: can you explain? I'm missing what your saying...

Comment: $\rm 10^n = (2\cdot 5)^n = 2^n\cdot 5^n\:$